# Django alias redirect on wrong url to the correct url

Tags: python, django, redirect

The question may have been asked many times, but I couldn't find something about this which is a basic stuff to do. I have a problem with my website one of the sub urls of google search redirects to the wrong page.

**Here are the urls :**

```
www.example.com/login/user/ #wrong url

www.example.com/accounts/login/ #correct url

urls.py : url(r'^accounts/login/$', auth_views.login, name='login'),
```

I'd like the user to be redirected to the correct url if he access the wrong one. I know that it is possible to do that with views using `redirect(reverse('...'))` but doing it just for this purpose doesn't sound like the best way.

Is there a way to redirect an user when he enters a wrong url to another one only by using `urls.py` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would normally do this on your webserver, e.g. Apache

```
RewriteRule /login/user/ /accounts/login/ [R=301,L]
```

That way you don't need to load Django to do a static redirect (you might build up a longer list of these as site-designs evolve).

Comment: Oh that's definitely a good solution ! I need to explore it !

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to use the `RedirectView` inside `urls.py` as shown here in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/class-based-views/base/#redirectview)

So, for example:

```
url(r'^login/user$', RedirectView.as_view(pattern_name='login')),
```

Answer (score 0):

To `urls.py`, you can add:

```
url(r'^login/user/$', auth_views.login, name='login')
```

It seems like you are aware of that. Did I not understand your question?

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't redirect, but stay on the page with login/user, is there a way to make the url change to accounts/login ?